# How can I show a modal after BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show a modal then call a method via BackgroundWorker, but it doesn't

I did this.

```
BackgroundWorker2 enviarSegundoPlano = new BackgroundWorker2();
enviarSegundoPlano.DoWork += 
    new BackgroundWorker2.DoWorkEventHandler(EnviarSegundoPlano_DoWork); //do the method

enviarSegundoPlano.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Modal", "fondoModal();", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Modal2", "openModalListaCirculares();", true); //this is the modal that I want to show
```

Comment: Why not moving to something more javascript friendly like asp.net MVC or ASP.NET core?

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync` method need to be called after adding event handler to BackgroundWorker.DoWork event.

The second sample code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-2.2 may help you.